merging multiple lidar sensor
Actually iam having problem with this question could please explain what to do
here is the question:   assume a 2-lidar configuration (diagonally placed) on an AMR. assume scanning range is 0-270 degrees. obtain scan data from both lidars and stitch based on transformations to get 360 field of view.  in ROS2 humble

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can use the ros2_lidar_scan_merger package to accomplish this, you'll just have to set up your two lidars published topics correctly, and match it with what is done in the merger config. The config is also where you setup the physical relations between the two, and the frame to publish on as center (ex laser1, base_link, etc).
As this package isn't published, you will have to build from source. I used it on Jazzy, but it should work for humble as it was built for Foxy.
https://github.com/mich1342/ros2_laser_scan_merger

thank you for your response! i have implemented it but there is error in Qos for both the nodes that is merger node and visualizer node could you just tell what to do

IIRC, you have to change the durability, history, and reliability of the RVIZ viewer to match what is in your laser_merge_params file, test if the error only occurs when you launch rviz.

yes the error occur only when i launch rviz eventhough  I changed QOS policies of rviz file according to params files of laser_merge

make sure you change both the particle cloud and laser params, I find it helpful to edit them in rviz, as it will give you immediate feedback if you got it right.

hello sir! i have changed the parameters which you suggested but still same errors persist i dont what to do, could you give me any other suggestions
